# Maximal Velocity of an Object in Free Fall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, free-fall

A baseball is dropped from a high point. Since the velocity is large, we can say that the drag force is proportional to the square of the velocity, $F_d = \gamma v^2$. My goal is to determine the maximal (terminal) velocity of the ball.

My attempt to solve the problem started with some simple force balancing:$$ F = ma = -mg + \gamma v^2 $$
Because I'm solving for v(t), I took $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$:
$$ m \frac{dv}{dt} = -mg+\gamma v^2$$ 
I then took the integral of both sides multiplied by dt:
$$ \int \frac{m}{mg-\gamma v^2}dv = \int-dt $$ 
$$m\int \frac{1}{g-\frac{\gamma}{m}v^2}dv = -\int dt$$ 
At this point, the integral becomes very complicated and it is difficult to solve for v(x). I'm sure there's a simpler way to solve this problem, but I just can't see it. What am I overlooking?

Comment: You don't need to do a single integral to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the ball has reached the terminal velocity, this doesn't increase anymore, and therefore $\dot v=0$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Ah, $$ \gamma v^2 = mg $$ $$ v = \sqrt{ \frac {mg}{\gamma}} $$
That's a pretty big thing to overlook, I guess all the calculus we've been doing in the lecture misled me. Thanks!